# button should delete specific item on server side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm working on an app to track my expenses with javascript, nodejs , express and as templating engine handelbars.

So I have a div "list" which contains all expenses. ( i have an add button next to the div list, not visible on the pic)

[image]

Everytime a I add an expense ,  I add the div "obj" with a delete button ,a "B" button and some information about the expense.

here is the code in my html:

```
<div class="list">

{{#each expArr}}
    <div id="obj" class="obj">
     <form action="/removetodo" method="POST" >
     <button class="btn2">X</button> 
    </form>

    <button onclick="openNav()" class="btn">B</button>
    <a>{{date}}</a> <n>{{name}}</n> <a>{{value}} </a>
    {{description}}  
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Now, my backend is runnning on a NodeJS server with express.

here is my index.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var expArr = [];


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index' , {expArr: expArr} );
});

 router.post('/addtodo', function (req, res, next) {



 var exp = new Object();

 exp.name = req.body.name;
 exp.value = req.body.val;
 exp.date = req.body.date;
 exp.description = req.body.descr;




 expArr.push(exp);
 res.redirect('/');

  });
 router.post('/removetodo', function (req, res, next) {


 expArr.pop();

 res.redirect("/");

 });


  module.exports = router;
```

In addtodo I simply adding all the informtion to an array on the server (later I will add a database).

Now my question:

The delete button on every expense should delete the right expense.
In other words, I want ,by clicking the delete button , that the right entry in the array on the server deletes.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Identify each expense by a unique identifier. An easy one is the timestamp at which it was first received by the server. Then have the button call a "/delete" route with the timestamp to delete as an argument, and have the server splice from the array of expenses the one with matching timestamp.

Comment: Agreed with above. Are you storing anything in any sort of database or repository? You need a way to uniquely identify each of the rows. You can then insert this into each HTML row and grab it before sending to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're storing everything in memory, taking that for granted, you can start by using a plain object rather then an array to store your data

```
expArr = {}
```

and then add a unique identifier like a hash or a date in ms for each instance

```
var exp = new Object();
exp.id = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
exp.name = req.body.name;
exp.value = req.body.val;
exp.date = req.body.date;
exp.description = req.body.descr;

expArr[exp.id] = exp;
```

now be sure to pass from the client the right id when you want to remove an expense

```
router.post('/removetodo', function (req, res, next) {
 if(expArr[req.body.id]) {
   delete expArr[req.body.id];
 }
 res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: ok thanks for ur help! Thats my question actually: How do I pass the right ID from the client to the server?

Comment: my first idea to solve this problem: Everytime I creating the button for each item , the buttons id should increment +1. And then i can get every buttons ID and compare it with the right array entry on my server. But I dont know how to increment the id of button which I create dynamically

Comment: the important is the uniqueness of the id. i gave you an example with a date in ms, but you can use a hash, or a different mechanism. just be sure is unique :)